# Detecting if gerrit patch needs a rebase, using gerrit/git command line?

Tags: git, rest, gerrit

I'm looking for a way to detect that gerrit patchset needs a rebase using command line tools.

Don't see a way to accomplish it using ssh gerrit review/query commands

I just need to know if the patch is rebased , not rebase it. I would also like to do it without fetching the whole repository 1st.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a change is mergeable using REST. Try to use the following example:

```
curl -s --request GET --netrc https://GERRIT-SERVER/a/changes/CHANGE-NUMBER/check | sed 1d | jq --raw-output ".mergeable"
```

Output:

- true = Mergeable
- false = Not mergeable

Sem more details at Gerrit documentation [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#check-change).

Comment: Actually saw that, but wasn't sure if with strategy set to "Rebase if Necessary" it will still give me a correct indication.

Comment: Just checked and it doesn't work. A patchset that is not rebased shows as mergeable.

Comment: Uhm... this doesn't make sense. Check if the "Allow content merges" option is "True" at project options.

Comment: Allow content merges set to True. And I think it makes sense - it is only not mergeable if there is a merge conflict detected. as long as there is no expected merge conflicts, it is indeed counted as mergeable.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted you. When you wrote "the patchset needs a rebase" I thought you meant "the patchset is not mergeable" or "the patchset needs a manual rebase (conflict resolution)". My mistake. But... why do you need to know if the change needs a rebase? If the change is mergeable Gerrit will perform the rebase automatically if necessary.

Comment: CI runs on a non-rebased patch which causes it to be tested with other code in the repository which and then stuff breaks after gerrit rebases and merges it. I need to abort CI if the patch is not rebased in order to force user to rebase.

Comment: If you require that any change is upmerged then I think it's better to use the "Fast Forward Only" submit type instead of "Rebase If Necessary", isn't it? See: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/project-configuration.html

Comment: If I understand how it works, FFO enforces rebase before submit, it doesn't prevent people from pushing to gerrit. Which means CI will still trigger. I need to block it from wasting too many resources.

Comment: I don't think some extra builds (due to some not upmerged pushes) will waste too many resources, but anyway, the important is that it'll be impossible to submit without rebase and then, in a near future, everyone will get used to perform a rebase before the push.